# Can you scale the scope of the Proportional Editing without a 3 button mouse?

Tags: edit-mode

Im trying to use Proportional Editing.
I don't have a 3 button mouse.
Is there a way to modify the field of influence without having a scroll wheel?
I already have "emulate 3 button mouse" and "emulate num pad" turned on.

---

*Update: Turns out, the Apple Magic Mouse that Im using does allow a scroll function if you swipe it down the middle. So I am able to get the functionality I am after. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.*

Comment: Im on a macbook air, and the trackpad just work like spected with 2 fingers gesture.

Also, if you have a wacom with touch you can also do the gesture of the 2 fingers.

Answer (score 13):

Use the <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys to adjust the circle of influence.

[image: Proportional Edit]

Comment: Im using a Mac with the small keyboard. (Makes most key commands a little challenging with 3D apps. : ) ) Unfortunately, there are no Page Up Page Down keys on this keyboard. I did however discover that the Apple Magic Mouse that Im using does allow a scroll wheel type of function if you swipe it down it's middle. So I think Im all set. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasBricker Could you please click the check mark under the voting arrows to show this as the correct solution?

Comment: @ThomasBricker fn right and fn left are your page up/down keys.

Comment: What worked for me here in Blender 3.4.1 is Fn and the up/down arrow keys

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround, but it isn't terribly convenient:

After you've completed the action, in the tool operator, which can be found in the tool bar <kbd>T</kbd> or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>, you can change the Proportional size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using a magic mouse and you can not change the circle of influence?
Well this works for me:

1. Select the points.
2. Activate the proportional editing button.
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd>.
4. Use two fingers to scroll up or down in your magic mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> key on the numpad if you have a full sized keyboard to increases or decrease the circle size in *Proportional Editing* mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm using blender 2.79. None of the above worked for me, here's what did:

Select the vertex/vertices you want to edit, left click and drag until proportional circle appears (if you can't see it you should see a line on the top left screen showing the proportional editing values).

Keep left button held down and scroll up or down (or click <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>⬆ Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>⬇ Page Down</kbd>).

Also note that under user preferences I had emulate 3 button mouse selected.

Answer (score -2):

After choosing proportional followed by  <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>G</kbd> etc use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> 1/2 to resize influence size

Comment: What is "`Shift + 1/2`"?